# POST username and password in JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, url

I have a web service I am working with a url such as

```
//myurl/index.jsp?user_name=bob&user_pwd=new
```

as you can see the username has been set as "bob" and password "new". The site give this json file when entered,

```
[{"success":"1"}]
```

How do you implemented it on xcode, where when a user enters `"bob"` as username and `"new"` as password it should lead to the next controller. How do can I achieve that ?

I followed this [tutorial](http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/03/iphoneios-programming-login-screen-post-data-url-parses-json-response/5/) though it's not quite the same, how do you do this. Thanks.

Comment: What problem you are facing? what u have try?

Answer (score 2):

Use a navigation controller and set you view controller as the rootViewController. Then after the user has entered the credentials push the new view controller onto the navigation stack.

Comment: I have implemented that already is an alternative but I need the app to post the username and password to the webservice url and check it it matches, then if it does , push to the next controller using a navigtion controller

Comment: What is your problem. You can just check the JSON you get back and push the next view controller when the answer states a success.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of success from json response. If it is equal to 1 then push to next controller else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In Following code you can pass data by either  `GET` or `POST` method … use any one (***As You Wish***)

```
-(void) sendRequest
{
  //////////////////////////// GET METHOD  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl/index.jsp?user_name=bob&user_pwd=new"];
    self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

 //////////////////////////// POST METHOD  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&user_name=bob&user_pwd=new"];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl/index.jsp/"];

    self.request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [self.request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(self.nsCon)
    {
        self.receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Not Connected !!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Connection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [GeneralClass stopHUD];
    NSLog(@"Connection failed.");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection failed!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; alert = nil;
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableDictionary *receivedData = [responseString JSONValue];

        if([[receivedData objectForKey:@"success"]  isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            MainDetailViewController *mdController = [[MainDetailViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mdController animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",receivedData);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, but how do I make a method for the sign in button, I am quite confused

Comment: create button with is method ...and call **sendRequest** method in button method

Comment: u need to call only ** sendRequest** method :)  either with in viewDidload or Button action method ...thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Post login data

```
    NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&data={\"LoginUser\":[{\"UserName\":\"%@\",\"Password\":\"%@\"}]}",firstname.text, password.text];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ soapMsg UTF8String ] length: [ soapMsg length ] ];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myRequestData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/index.jsp"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Receive and vaild json data

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:WebXmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
        BOOL success = [[results objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];

        if (success) {
             ViewController *viewController =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];    
        }


    }
```

Comment: Instances should not begin with a capital letter.

Comment: I am slightly confused, do you put the first set of code in the viewdidload method and the second on my signin button method ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer you are looking for but this is more a recommendation for what should you use.
I use [github link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for Network related activities. 
They have nice documentation and very easy to use (uses blocks)

```
NSDictionary *paramsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"user",@"client_id",@"password",@"new", nil];

    [[YourAFHttpClientExtenstion sharedInstance] postPath:LOGIN_PATH parameters:paramsDictionary success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //handle success

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       // handle error.
    }];
```

YourAFHttpClientExtenstion is extending AFHttpClient and adds a convening method of shared instance and implements initWithBaseUr: